# rspec message expectations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

подскажите, как повесить несколько идентичных message expectations в rspec?

ситуация такая - перебираю коллекцию и хочу, чтобы вешались ожидания по содержимому коллекции.
**вот код, который я хочу протестировать:**

```
args.keys.each do |attach|
      file      = File.open args[attach]['file']
      content   = file.read
      hash      = Digest::MD5.base64digest(content)
      upload_id = Gis::HouseManagement::Main.gis_files_upload(content, args[attach]['filename'], store, hash, org_ppa_guid)
      next unless upload_id

      guids['upload_guids'][attach]                = {}
      guids['upload_guids'][attach]['upload_guid'] = upload_id
      guids['upload_guids'][attach]['filename']    = args[attach]['filename']
      guids['upload_guids'][attach]['hash']        = hash

      File.unlink file
end
```

**вот тест**

```rb
args.keys.each do |attach|
        file      = args[attach]['file']
        content   = 'some content'
        hash      = Digest::MD5.base64digest(content)
        upload_id = Gis::HouseManagement::Main
                        .gis_files_upload(content, args[attach]['filename'], store, hash, org_ppa_guid)

        expect(File).to receive(:open).with(args[attach]['file']).and_return file
        expect(Digest::MD5).to receive(:base64digest).with(content).and_return hash

        expect(Gis::HouseManagement::Main)
            .to receive(:gis_files_upload)
                    .with(content, args[attach]['filename'], store, hash, org_ppa_guid).and_return(upload_id)
        if upload_id
          expect(File).to receive(:unlink).with(file)
        end
      end

      perform_enqueued_jobs { job }
```

сама коллекция args выглядит так:

```rb
{"project_registration_node"=>{"file"=>"/tmp/project20191212-29922-fjyl43", "filename"=>"project.txt"}, "certificate"=>{"file"=>"/tmp/certificate20191212-29922-1489k1", "filename"=>"certificate.txt"}}
```

получаю ошибку

```
RSpec::Mocks::MockExpectationError: #<File (class)> received :open with unexpected arguments
  expected: ("/tmp/project20191212-29509-1u7mbp8")
       got: ("/tmp/certificate20191212-29509-1bwrat6")

  0) Gis::HouseManagement::CreateMeteringDeviceJob test will pass
     Failure/Error: file    = File.open args[attach]['file']

       #<File (class)> received :open with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("/tmp/project20191212-29509-1u7mbp8")
              got: ("/tmp/certificate20191212-29509-1bwrat6")
```

типа такое ожидание уже есть...
это после первой итерации. на второй.

подскажите, как решить?

Comment: А где код вашего теста, который выдаёт ошибку?

Comment: запарился что-то) добавил код теста

Comment: Попробуйте поставить ограничение количества - `expect(File).to receive(:open).with(args[attach]['file']).at_least(:once).and_return(file)`

Comment: Так сработает. Но мне бы по всей коллекции пройтись.

Comment: Таким образом и пройдёт по всей коллекции, вы же в итераторе `expect` вызываете

Comment: не сработало. опять берет следующее по итерации значение и вылетает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в общем, я решил изменить тест. я вынес тестируемый код в отдельный метод, благо он нужен в нескольких местах, и теперь буду тестировать результат на выходе, а не работу самого кода. всем спасибо, вопрос можно считать снятым.лучшим я пометил этот ответ потому, что изначально неправильно было так детально всё тестировать. это не оставляет места для рефакторинга и делает тесты 'хрупкими'